# Java - Remove keys matching regex from JsonObject

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm able to remove the key from JsonObject using:

```
String prop = "test";
JsonObject o = parser.parse(props).getAsJsonObject();
o.remove(prop);
```

I need to remove all the keys matching certain pattern from the JsonObject, like anything that starts with "test.*". Instead of iterating over the keys and find a match, is there any other way to remove the keys matching a given pattern?

```
input: {"test":"0","test_1": "1","test_10":"10", "site":"abc.com"}
expected output: {"site":"abc.com"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a input / output example please

Comment: iterate over keys and check for `contains` your test string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.

The best you can do is compile the regex before the loop to improve performance:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(prop);
Iterator<Entry<...>> it = o.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<...> entry = it.next();
    if (pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).matches()) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```